# MariaDB Case statement

Tags: sql, mariadb, case

I have the following SQL-Code in a Mariadb-Database:
(1)

```
select Labornummer, Matrix, FaktorGW, FaktorAW
from gc_Faktoren
```

I need the following result:

If Matrix='AW' => I need the field "FaktorAW"

else =>  I need the field "FaktorGW"

is it possible to formulate Statement (1) with a "case statement"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, this is possible.
Basically you can do this:

```
SELECT labornummer, matrix, faktoraw, faktorgw,
CASE WHEN matrix = 'AW' THEN faktoraw
ELSE faktorgw END AS factor
FROM gc_faktoren;
```

You have to take care if this is really exactly what you want, e.g. this will not check lower/upper case. See the working example:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=eea00b4a560a874b5e11a748e7636e35)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select Labornummer, Matrix, FaktorGW, FaktorAW, 
CASE
 WHEN Matrix = 'AW' THEN FaktorAW ELSE FaktorGW END as New_Field
from gc_Faktor
```